# Memory resource increase non stop

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I am new to GLFW and made a simple texture mapping program. Problem is while running the program the memory resource increases non stop which I can see clearly in taskmanager.

After running the program for a few minutes, my computer's fan speeds up and a heating problem occurs. How can I fix this problem?

Here is code for texture loading function

```
GLuint LoadTexture(const char* TextureName)
{
    GLuint Texture;  //variable for texture
    glGenTextures(1,&Texture); //allocate the memory for texture
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,Texture); //Binding the texture

    if(glfwLoadTexture2D(TextureName, GLFW_BUILD_MIPMAPS_BIT)){
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
        return Texture;
    }else return -1;
}
```

Here is code for draw function

```
void display()
{
    glClearColor( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f ); //clear background screen to black

    //Clear information from last draw
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT| GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); //Switch to the drawing perspective
    glLoadIdentity(); //Reset the drawing perspective

    glTranslatef(0.0f,0.0f,-35.0f); //Translate whole scene to -ve z-axis by -35 unit


    GLuint text2D;
    text2D = LoadTexture("cicb.tga"); //loading image for texture

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D); //Enable texture
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,text2D);//Binding texture

    glPushMatrix();
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON); //Begin quadrilateral coordinates
    glNormal3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);//normal vector
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); //Texture co-ordinate origin or  lower left corner
    glVertex3f(-10.0f,-11.0f,5.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); //Texture co-ordinate lower right corner
    glVertex3f(10.0f,-11.0f,5.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);//Texture co-ordinate top right corner
    glVertex3f(10.0f,-1.0f,-15.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);//Texture co-ordinate top left corner
    glVertex3f(-10.0f,-1.0f,-15.0f);

    glEnd(); //End quadrilateral coordinates
    glPopMatrix();
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);


    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,text2D);
    glPushMatrix();

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glNormal3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);//Texture co-ordinate origin or lower left corner
    glVertex3f(-10.0f,-1.0f,-15.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(10.0f, 0.0f); //Texture co-ordinate for repeating image ten times form
    //origin to lower right corner
    glVertex3f(10.0f,-1.0f,-15.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(10.0f, 10.0f);//repeat texture ten times form lower to top right corner.
    glVertex3f(10.0f,15.0f,-15.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 10.0f);//repeat texture ten time form top right to top left corner.
    glVertex3f(-10.0f,15.0f,-15.0f);
    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D); //Disable the texture
    glfwSwapBuffers();

}
```

If anyone want to see the problem by running exe then I can provide download link.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You seem to be loading your texture each time you call `display()`. (Once per frame in essence) I assume that is what is taking all your memory at some point. You just want to do this once outside of your display function.

Comment: When I call the LoadTexture Funtion outside the display() function it doesn't load image but return 1. I have made GLuint global variable and assigned the value return by LoadTexture function to that variable and used it in display() function. What mistake I have done.

Comment: That `1` might be the exact result you get from glGenTextures. (i.e. everything is fine) To indicate an error you might want to return `-1` instead. Just hook up a debugger and see what values you get and what execution path is taken.

Comment: Sorry Bart, Iam sure your answer is correct. Iam good in C++ but I tried hard but failed.I compiled in codeblock here is poject file https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6iurx6sgps4oloc/p5IH070ykM/TextureGLFW.rar would you please download and see my complete code what silly mistake I have done. It is small program.

Comment: @dineshsubedi: With OpenGL use 0 as a return code, because 0 is a special object ID refering to the default (nil) of OpenGL. So glGen… never gives a 0 as ID. Also you must make sure that OpenGL functions are only called when a OpenGL context is available. In your case only after creating the GLFW window. BTW: Positive numbers never are a good error indicator. What makes you think that 1 was suitable for error indication in the first place? Usually in C and C++ if a numeric return value indicates failure it's either zero or negative.